# How to write NUnit test for this method using the interface for mocking?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, nunit, mocking

This is the exact representation of a WCF interface and class that I have.

I would like to know how to write a NUnit test for this... using the interface for mocking.

The main thing is I am NOT looking to add a service reference for the WCF service integration test. But some thing more concentrated for the unit testing part. Specifically to test the ProcessStuff method.

```
namespace CompanyName.Services.ProcessStuff {
 public class ProcessStuffService : IProcessStuff
    {

        public string ProcessStuff(string input)
        {
            ISomeOtherInterface ProcessManager = new ProcessManager();
            return ProcessManager.ProcessStuff(input);            
        }

    }
}


namespace CompanyName.Common.FacadeInterfaces
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "com.companyname.services", Name = "Process Stuff Service")]
    public interface IProcessStuff
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "ProcessStuff")]
        string ProcessStuff(string input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I might have mis-read the question, so feel free to clarify.

If the method under test is:

```
ProcessManager.ProcessStuff(input)
```

The IProcessStuff interface is irrelevant. You would create a new Process Manager and call this method.

```
// You would pass mocks IN to the process manager if it required them here...
var processManager = new ProcessManager();
var result = processManager.ProcessStuff(testInput);
Assert.IsNotNull(result);
```

So in this case, I cannot see what Interface you want to mock.